# EF is not saving changes

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I really hope someone can help me. I have following controller-action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel vm)
    {
        Item item= db.Items.Find(vm.ItemId);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //breakpoint 1 --> everything works fine, if its debugged step by step from here

            //if item´s contact is null or different from viewmodel --> override it
            if (item.Contact == null || item.Contact.ContactId != vm.ContactId)
                item.Contact = db.Contacts.Find(vm.ContactId);

            //if the viewmodel have a ContractUnit set and its different from item´s --> override the contractunit
            //is the ContractUnit in viewmodel null set item´s null too
            if (vm.ContractUnitId.HasValue && ((item.ContractUnit != null && item.ContractUnit.ContractUnitId != vm.ContractUnitId) || item.ContractUnit == null))
                item.ContractUnit = db.ContractUnits.Find(vm.ContractUnitId);
            else 
                if (!vm.ContractUnitId.HasValue)
                    item.ContractUnit = null;

            //same as above just for Building
            if (vm.BuildingId.HasValue && ((item.Building != null && item.Building.BuildingId != vm.BuildingId) || item.Building == null))
                item.Building = db.Buildings.Find(vm.BuildingId);
            else 
                if (!vm.BuildingId.HasValue)
                    item.Building = null;

            //same as above just for EconomicUnit
            if (vm.EconomicUnitId.HasValue && ((item.EconomicUnit != null && item.EconomicUnit.EconomicUnitId != vm.EconomicUnitId) || item.EconomicUnit == null))
                item.EconomicUnit = db.EconomicUnits.Find(vm.EconomicUnitId);
            else 
                if (!vm.EconomicUnitId.HasValue)
                    item.EconomicUnit = null;

            //breakpoint 2 --> (no changes to item, if its the first breakpoint)
            item= vm.GetItem(item); //override non relational data
            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
...
  }
```

Method GetItem from EditViewModel:

```
    public Item GetItem(Item item)
    {
        item.DateReported = this.DateReported; //Datetime
        item.Description = this.Description; //String
        item.FirstDeadline = this.FirstDeadline; //Datetime
        item.SecondDeadline = this.SecondDeadline; //Datetime
        item.ThirdDeadline = this.ThirdDeadline; //Datetime
        item.ReplacementDeadline = this.ReplacementDeadline; //Datetime
        return item;
    }
```

The Problem: EF is not saving the changes to item.Building, item.ContractUnit or item.EconomicUnit. But it does when i am debugging it step by step.
There is no error or exception thrown and the viewmodel and model is filled properly.

I really hope someone can help me to solve this...

Comment: You might get a better chance of finding an answer yourself or someone helping you, by reducing the code to the minimum code required to demonstrate the problem. Ideally create a brand new solution for this. Also post connection strings, your EF initialisation code, etc.

Comment: Actually i have reduced the code to everything that is affecting this behavior. Everything else is working fine and as well as the connection string. My problem is that ef is not reflecting the changes to the database unless i am debugging is step by step.

Comment: What does the GetItem do? How does the code look for that?

Comment: Without knowing what path the code chooses, it is too hard for us to work out. Get rid of the if or else blocks that are not relevant for the problem. Comment them out temporarily. Put the breakpoint further down. Sorry but we are not a debugger.

Comment: Just added the method GetItem and more comments to explain what i try to do. Sorry, i should have added them right from the beginning.

Comment: What if you comment out the ifs and just add a value explicitly to item. let say `item.Building = db.Buildings.Find(add a id you know excist);`, the point of this is to see if finds it and set it.

Comment: I tried it, with the same result. Without breakpoint the Building, EconomicUnit and ContractUnit are not changed and debugging step by step saves all changes.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the relations from the item-model and now only save the ids in a "long?" attribute. Well, its now additional work to get the related data but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
DBSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
```

before

```
db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Maybe this helps.